# Translated Content with ng-repeat $timeout and refresh. (from a static json)

Tags: angularjs, timeout, refresh, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-translate

i have some trouble with translated content and ng-repeat.
Before i was reading everything content related from a js file
with scope and then the categories.

Like

```
jobs{
   headline:..
   subline:...
},
jobs{
   headline:..
   subline:...
}
```

Now i want to put this content into my json file.
I was testing some things and its currently working with 
$translate.instant

like:

```
  $scope.jobs = [
    {
      headline: $translate.instant('jobs.headline'),
      subheadline: $translate.instant('jobs.subline'),
}
```

But:

1. Sometimes the ng-repeat fires before it loads the json file - so i get bad results
2. When i change the language  - its not refreshing the ng-repeat module or loading in the diffrent languages.

What would you do? 
Whats the best way to deal with ng-repeat and $translate?

//My suggestion was something like a timeout and refreshOnSuccess or so.

Comment: have you tried timeout function

Comment: Thanks Timeout is working! To my second question: Is there a way to refresh the ng-repeat module when the language changes ?

Comment: Solved it: 

The magic lays behind the events:
[http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/18_events][1]


  [1]: http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/18_events

With $translateLoadingSuccess and $translateChangeEnd you can listen to everything and change it on the fly. 
Its better then $timeout. 

Also remember thats only working with $rootScope

Comment: Sorry for my bad comment style, but im disallowed to post answers :(